# Azure Powershell Command failure when using Invoke-AzsRegistrationValidation

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-stack

I have been following the steps given here(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure-stack/operator/azure-stack-validate-registration?view=azs-2008&tabs=az) to validate a subscription but when i run the invoke command it fails with the below error:

> ```
> > PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Invoke-AzsRegistrationValidation
> > -RegistrationSubscriptionID $subscriptionID Invoke-AzsRegistrationValidation : Parameter set cannot be resolved
> > using the specified named parameters. At line:1 char:1
> > + Invoke-AzsRegistrationValidation -RegistrationSubscriptionID $subscri ...
> > + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> >     + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-AzsRegistrationValidation], ParentContainsErrorRecordExcept   
> > ion
> >     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousParameterSet,Invoke-AzsRegistrationValidation
> ```

Answer (score 0):

The obvious question is do you have the correct subscriptionID in `$SubscriptionID`

The doc you reference suggest some logs might be created, is there anything in them that help?

**Log location (contains PII):**
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\AzsReadinessChecker\AzsReadinessChecker.log**
s
**Report location (contains PII):**
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\AzsReadinessChecker\AzsReadinessCheckerReport.json